# How to get html table data when columns are inconsistent in R (rvest)

Tags: r, rvest

I want to extract table data from the website **https://www.mohfw.gov.in/**
It has ***inconsistent*** column structure so I can not easlily extract it. I have tried as below but only header details I can get but not actual data inside table.

```
library(rvest)
url='https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'
webpage <- read_html(url)
table <- html_node(webpage, "table.statetable.table.table-striped")
frame <- html_table(table,fill = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Network tab of Dev Tools and reload the page. You will see the page loads data from this JSON file: https://www.mohfw.gov.in/data/datanew.json

You can read it by:

```
table <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.mohfw.gov.in/data/datanew.json")
```